# Is there an API to get the iOS Rapid Security Response version?

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice

Rapid Security Responses are a recent introduction which allows Apple to provide OS updates that fix security issues without the need to install a full software update.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201224

Is there an iOS API I can use to get the Rapid Security Response version? The version is a suffix to the OS version e.g. (a), (b), etc, but I don't mind having an API that gives me the full version e.g. 16.4.1 (a).

I don't see any information on any iOS API for that in the Apple Developer docs. There is an API for MDM solutions in the resource above, but that's not what I really need.

I have tried `UIDevice.current.systemVersion` to see if it contains the suffix when run on a Rapid Security Response OS version, but it doesn't (Apple doing that instead of introducing a new API would break lots of existing code anyway, but it was worth a shot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the iOS side it's possible to get it from `ProcessInfo`

```
var info = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString
info = info.replacingOccurrences(of: "Version ", with: "")

let buildRegex = " \\(Build.*\\)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: buildRegex, options: [])
let version = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(
    in: info,
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: info.count),
    withTemplate: ""
)
```

Also, use MDM API to retrieve if the rapid update is available.
Endpoint: https://gdmf.apple.com/v2/pmv

Comment: Is that `gdmf` API severely rate limited? I seem to get blocked almost immediately when I make a few calls to it within a several minute timespan.